Find minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^{*}$
So this is part of an exercise sheet where I thought I had figured it out but turns out I didn't.

Theory from lecture: 
We know for a prime $p$ the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(m)$ where $m$ is some monic irreducible (over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$) polynomial of degree n. We also know the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ has order $p-1$ for a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $p$ prime.

Part 1 (solved): For $p^n=9$ find such a minimal polynomial. 
We have $\mathbb{F}_{9}=\mathbb{F}_{3²}\simeq \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(m_2)$ where $m_2$ has degree 2 and is monic and irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

I guessed $m_2(x) = x²+1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$ since $m_2(0) = 0²+1=1\neq0$, $m_2(1) = 1²+1=2\neq0$ and $m_2(2)=2²+1=2\neq0$.
Remains to check a root $\alpha$ of $m_2$ is really a generator of $\mathbb{F}_3^*$. We therefore check the order of $\alpha$: 
Firstly, note $\alpha$ a root $\implies$ $m_2(\alpha)=0=\alpha²+1 \iff \alpha² = - 1 = 2 \in\mathbb{F}_3$ 
Then, 
$\alpha³=\alpha\alpha²=2\alpha$
$\alpha⁴=(\alpha²)²=4=1 \in \mathbb{F}_3$. Hence, the order of $\alpha$ is $4\neq8\implies\alpha$ is not a generator.
Taking an educated guess and trying $(\alpha+1)$ yields 
$(\alpha+1)²=\alpha²+2\alpha+1=2\alpha$ (since $\alpha²=-1$)
$(\alpha+1)³=(\alpha+1)(\alpha+1)²=2\alpha(\alpha+1)=2\alpha²+2\alpha=2\alpha-2$
$(\alpha+1)⁴=((\alpha+1)²)²=4\alpha²=-4=-1\in\mathbb{F}_3$
Hence, $1=(-1)²=((\alpha+1)⁴)²=(\alpha+1)⁸\implies \alpha+1$ has order 8 and is hence a generator of $\mathbb{F}_3^*$. Now we need to find a minimal polynomial of $\alpha+1$. Above we find $(\alpha+1)²=2\alpha \iff (\alpha+1)²-2\alpha=0 \iff (\alpha+1)²-2(\alpha+1)+2=0$ hence $\alpha+1$ is a root of $m_2'=x²-2x+2=x²+x+2 \in\mathbb{F}_3$. This is our desired polynomial.
Part 2 (need help): For $p^n=16$ find such a minimal polynomial. 
Like above we find $\mathbb{F}_{16}=\mathbb{F}_{2⁴}\simeq \mathbb{F}_{2}[x]/(m_4)$ where $m_4$ has degree 4 and is monic and irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

I guessed $m_4(x) = x⁴+x+1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ since $m_4(0) =1\neq0$ and $m_4(1) = 1\neq0$.
Remains to check a root $\alpha$ of $m_4$ is really a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{16}^*$, hence has order 15. We therefore check the order of $\alpha$: 
Firstly, note $\alpha$ a root $\implies m_4(\alpha) = \alpha⁴+\alpha+1=0 \iff \alpha=\alpha⁴+1 \in \mathbb{F}_2$ Then, 
$\alpha²=(\alpha⁴+1)²=\alpha⁸+2\alpha⁴+1=\alpha⁸+1$ 
$\alpha³=\alpha\alpha²=\alpha⁹+\alpha$ 
$\alpha⁴=(\alpha²)²=\alpha^{16}+1$ 
$\alpha⁵=\alpha^{17}+\alpha$ but $\alpha^{15}=(\alpha⁵)³=(\alpha^{17}+\alpha)³=\alpha^{51}+3\alpha^{35}+3\alpha^{19}+\alpha³\neq1\implies \alpha$ not a generator? Please tell me there is a more intelligent way than guessing and computing all the orders of $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha-1$?

If $g$ is a generator, what is wrong with $x-g?$ Or do you want the polynomial that has roots all generators?  Then you want the cyclotomic polynomial, $\Phi_{p-1}.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

It seems like you want the minimal polynomial for a generator of $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p?$ That is not what your title says.

Even so, the idea that there are minimal polynomials is very confusing. All polynomials such that $\mathbb F_{p^n}=\mathbb F_p[x]/(m(x))$ are minimal.

You are using the minimal polynomial $x^4+x+1\in\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ in the wrong way. You are supposed to use it to turn higher powers of $\alpha$ into lower degree polynomials. See the list of consecutive powers of $\alpha$ near the end of this old answer of mine. What you denote by $\alpha$ is called $\gamma$ there, because I had used up $\alpha$ and $\beta$ earlier in that post :-)

If $p$ is a primitive root mod $p^n-1,$ then the minimal polynomial is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^n-1}.$ Because said polynomial will be irreducible (some more theory).  It looks like this almost never happens.
If not,  then $\Phi_{p^n-1}$ is reducible over $\Bbb F_p.$
An irreducible factor of deg $n$ will have $\alpha $ as a root.  And that's the minimal polynomial.
So in your second example,  we have $\Phi_{15}=x^8-x^7+x^5-x^4+x^3-x+1.$  Since $2$ is not primitive mod $15$ ($2^4\equiv1$), it's reducible.
We find the factorization $(x^4+x+1)(x^4-x^3+1).$
Now one of those is going to be the minimal polynomial (whichever has $\alpha $ as a root).
There are $\varphi (15)=8$ different generators of $\Bbb F_{16}^*,$ and depending on which one is $\alpha $ we get either the first or second factor as  the minimal polynomial.
Upshot: we need more information to find the actual minimal polynomial.   We need  to know more about $\alpha.$

Why would I talk over $\Bbb Q?$  We're in a finite field.   And, the minimal polynomial is unique.   @underflow

$p$ doesn't have two meanings.  There's only one $p.$  @underflow

@underflow since $\alpha $ is a root of the cyclotomic polynomial,  if it's irreducible it's the minimal polynomial.

Last comment,  because I think we're square now.   If it's reducible we need to find which factor is the minimal polynomial.   I thought you got that right.   That's why I upvoted.  @underflow
